# How to set Listview item size according to material design guidelines in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have seen google design guidelines and wants to implement that guidelines in my project ,but I did not understand guidelines bout list view item size in the following details like :- what is height 48 in the given below image and a red marked line is padding or margin.kindly explain me pls.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwmn4.png)

Answer (score 2):

48 is the height in density points. The vertical red lines are padding. The documentation is pretty clear: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#lists-actions

Comment: how to give that density height in xml

Comment: https://m3.material.io/components/lists/specs